# solr cloud: RROR: Error loading config name for collection

Tags: solrcloud

I'm trying to create a new collection with solr-cloud setup, fails with the following:

```
ERROR: Error loading config name for collection test
```

I tried deleting the collection:

```
sudo /opt/solr/bin/solr delete -c test
```

but with the same results

My setup:  solr-cloid with external zookeeper and 5 solr nodes
How do I purge it or reload it again ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solr is not able to find configuration files in zookeeper. Solrcloud try to recreate the core from zookeeper configuration file.
Looks like you have deleted zookeeper configuration node for collection test.

Two steps to completely purge collection test:

1. Stop solr and Delete folder "test" if exists from Solr home folder.(default: /var/lib/solr)
2. Navigate to zookeeper node and edit clusterstate.json . Remove entries of collection test. I wanted to start fresh so reset clusterstate.json file to default i.e {}

you should disable autoAddReplicas property of solr before shutting down  any solrnode.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the config folder exists in zookeeper. If this is the case, try to link the collection with the configname using the commmand:

```
zkcli.sh -cmd linkconfig -collection collectionname -confname configname
```